# vscode remote-ssh fails

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

Local: macOS 12.6, vscode1.72.2, remote-ssh v0.90.1 preview

Server: Tencent Cloud Lightweight Server centOS7.6

Server ssh configuration is set: AllowTcpForwarding yes

The local command line ssh connection server can be entered normally.

The error message is:

channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific can you ssh from your terminal but you can't from vscode? What are you using in vscode to connect, a plugin?

Comment: yes, using Remote-SSH  in vscode

Comment: Can you share your configs on how you are doing ssh?

Comment: After installing the remote-ssh extension, configure the HostName and User, that's all, the port is the default 22

Comment: In the remote-ssh configuration of vscode, remove the tick of remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket, then kill all vscode-servers on linux, delete the ~/.vscode-server directory, and let it download again.it works,thanks so much